# How to fix i2c dev/node name mapping

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, i2c, device-tree

I am working on OpenEmbedded Linux project (Yocto BSP).

I am facing an issue regarding I2C dev-node name mapping, please refer to image at below:

[image]

I realized that mapping of left and right may not be the same again after re-imaging.

For example, i2c-20 map with 58226000.i2c, and after re-image (via recover mode), and the mapping is different, (i2c-20 map with 56246000.i2c).

I wish to fix the mapping for my image, is it need to do something in device tree ? Please teach me the method in details. Thanks.

Or any workaround, for example , do mapping manually during my application start ?

Comment: Which board are you using? Which version of the board's Linux and BSP Kernel?

Comment: Hi @CleitonBueno , I am using Toradex Apalis iMX8QXP 2GB WB IT - V1.1B

Comment: The Toradex kernel i2c alias for the imx8 board is here:

http://git.toradex.com/cgit/linux-toradex.git/tree/arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/imx8qxp.dtsi?h=toradex_5.4-2.3.x-imx


Where are you making these changes?

Comment: The rule of thumb, you mustn't use _/dev/i2c*_ at all. Write or enable proper driver for your hardware and use its specific interfaces. Btw, you may use names from the second column.